# Assign part of ArrayList to string

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` that I access in a fragment with the following code:

```
getData = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("importEvents");
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getData.split(",")));
myList.remove(0);
myList.remove(myList.size() - 1);
```

The output of this is as follows

```
Event1 (2017-03-13) 
Event2 (2017-03-14)
```

Each event starts on a new line following the second `)` but am I able to save everything before the first bracket as a separate string so I can assign it to another TextView in a CardView?

Comment: Let's say your list contains 4 items, you want to build a String with items with index 1 and 2? Please explain.

Comment: I'm seeing some problem in your code, the `myList.size()` will be changed once you remove the first item from the myList. So, store the size of list before you remove the first item

Comment: @Pons I want to separate the value of the array lists essentially into two parts - the name of the event, and then the date of the event. None of the other methods listed below have worked as yet.

Comment: I have placed answer for this requirement, please take a look and let me know if you have any questions. Let me know if i haven't understood you clearly

Answer (score 1):

```
myList.get(0).substring(0, myList.get(0).indexOf('('))
```

Comment: I get an error of "cannot resolve method 'subString(int,int)'"

Comment: sorry it will be substring

Comment: I had tried that fix, but it has no effect on the output. It shows no errors though

Comment: it should print only Event1. You should use a TextView to print that value.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below some sample to convert as per your requirement,

```
    String myString = "Event1 (2017-03-13) Event2 (2017-03-14)";
    myString = myString.replaceAll(" \\(", "\\(");

    List<Event> events = Arrays.asList(myString.split(" ")).stream()
            .map(event -> new Event(event.split("\\(")[0], event.split("\\(")[1].replaceAll("\\)", "")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(events);
```

**Create a POJO, Event class,**

```
    public class Event {

private String name;
private String date;

Event(String name, String date) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.name + "\t" + this.date;
}
```

}

**Sample Output**

`[Event Name - Event1    Date - 2017-03-13
, Event Name - Event2    Date - 2017-03-14
]`

This will give you an idea of how to split your string in to event and event date

Comment: I only used two events as an example, the overall string is actual google calendar events. I access it through the [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) and then extract the final value as the Array.
Would I assign the 'String myString' to be the final value retrieved from the calendar and process it like that?

Comment: @smithcommajohn I have made some changes. yes, you can assign the final value to `myString`. I have create another POJO `Event` to store the event information